# Why does an Outlook mail rule not work with Office365 undeliverability mails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, forwarding, mail-rule

We would like to forward incoming Office365 undeliverability mails ("Office 365 Your message to ... couldn´t be delivered ...) containing a special phrase within subject or body to a different mailbox. Unfortunately proper mail rules seem not to work with these type of incoming mails. Tests with "normal" incoming mails work fine. Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you still have doubts about this issue? If you have no doubt about the issue, you could mark the helpful reply as best answer or you could share your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge and testing on my lab, you seems cannot create a inbox rule or mail flow rule to forward NDRs to another users, since system-generated message couldn't be forwarded automatically.

In addition, here's a similar thread for your reference: [Setting up a rule to forward "undeliverable" reports (NDR) to a different mailbox](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/setting-up-a-rule-to-forward-undeliverable-reports/ef7e2f9c-85d5-4bd4-84dc-edaf27c9baac)

Comment: Thanks a lot Joy! Finally got the same info from Microsoft. At least move to another folder within mailbox does work. Better than nothing ;-)